Are the young boys all killed during the battle of the burning mill?
House of the Dragons, Season 2, ep 3, at the beginning, two groups of young boys from the Brackens and Blackwoods are arguing about boarders and their alliengce. The screen is cut to an aftermath of the battle of the burning mill.
We see a dead boy wearing the same sigil from the previous argument scene as well as a pin that is previously worn on another boy.
Are these characters killed off as soon as they are introduced in ep 3? As I was expecting there would be a story following their growth from young boys into adult knights.

We don't know for sure yet, but presumably they are killed.

We see one of them dead when the scene switches (Aeron Bracken, I believe). However, they are both TV show only characters and pretty much just used to set up the battle, I doubt we'll see the other again.
